# Як краще перекласти українською "download" та "upload"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Згідно означень:

- [Download](http://www.wordnik.com/words/download) - передавати дані, програми, текст тощо з віддаленого комп’ютера (сервера) до локального комп’ютера (зазвичай, через мережу), або з комп’ютера до периферійного пристрою.
- [Upload](http://www.wordnik.com/words/upload) - передавати дані чи програми від периферійного комп’ютера чи пристрою до центрального, зазвичай віддаленого, комп’ютера.

Колись я зустрічав переклад `download` - `звантажити` і `upload` - `завантажити`, але це може заплутати людей, адже зараз переважна більшість (зокрема й локалізованих [програм](http://www.opera.com/uk/computer/windows) та [сайтів](https://www.microsoft.com/uk-ua/download/details.aspx?id=3)) вживає `завантажити` у значенні `download`. Іноді можна почути сленг `залити` у значенні `upload`.

Розумію, що однозначної відповіді на це питання не існує, та все ж хочеться почути думки користувачів стосовно того, як би вони переклали `download` та `upload`.

Comment: сленг: `закинути`, `залити`. рідко `вивантажити` як антонім `завантажити`, що теж доволі недолуго, втім як і використання `завантажити` замість `звантажити` для `download`

Comment: О, самого давно це цікавить. Хоча навряд чи запропонують щось краще, ніж те, що Ви написали: завантажити/залити. Хоча [slovotvir для upload](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/upload) ще пропонує «відвантажити» (це топовий варіант; я так розумію, дії «завантажити» і «відвантажити» йдуть відносно користувача) і «замереж(ув)ити» (тобто в мережу).

Comment: Is the term "Skachaty" Russian slang? This is more idiomatic, as opposed to a technical term.

Comment: @nizz0k, Ukrainian language does have [скач(ув)ати](http://sum.in.ua/s/skachuvaty). I don't know why no dictionary or software package considers it as valid variant. I even saw that word in Ukrainian commercial in subway, which played with the similarity of the words [качати](http://sum.in.ua/s/kachaty) ("to download") and [качка](http://sum.in.ua/s/kachka) ("a duck") and depicted *a night duck* (as metaphor for night Internet user). http://verinet.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/nichna-kachka.jpg

Comment: @Sasha Я просто собі думав що то слово мало вплив від Російських термінів. Я жив в Києві десь рік і всі мої товариші так говорили -закачати, підкачати, накачав, ітд. Звісно це слов'янське слово, то розрішити питання його джерела не легко. Загально цікавлюсь етимологію то хотів спитатися :)

Comment: @nizz0k, так, мабуть, значення *download* слова «(с)кач(ув)ати» прийшло саме з російської мови. Але слово таке в українській було (просто скалькували значення). Я не знаю, добре це чи погано — мені здається, що не так уже й погано. Але, мабуть, саме через це (через кальковане походження) його в словники/софт не спішать добавляти.

Comment: Якщо кажете про переклад згідно комп'ютерного сучасного змісту, то мова йде про передачу інформації. Інформацію, або ж природніше знання, передають та приймають. Є й інші варіанти. load - вантажити, down та up - напрямок. download, upload - уявлення (абстрація) про передачу інформації зі вказаним напрямком передачі. Якщо дослівно, то вивантажити та увантажити. І саме такими словами. Не треба відштовхуватися від слова вантажити. Мова йде про абстракцію передачі різного типу інформації, зі вказанням напрямку. Можете вигадати свою абстрацію до передачі даних, інформації, знань. Але логіка така.

Comment: Спробуйте визначити поняття UP-LINK і DOWNLOAD-LINK, щоб швидше прийти до загальноприйнятної відповіді.

Answer (score 28):

Microsoft:

> [Download](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=download&langID=uk-ua) = завантажити.
>   [Upload](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=upload&langID=uk-ua) = передати <sub>(іноді: надіслати, завантажити)</sub>.

[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk):

> Download = отримати.
>   Upload = вивантажити.

Словотвір (лідери станом на 2017-03-02):

> [Download](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/download) = завантажити.
>   [Upload](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/upload) = відвантажити.

«Народний» словник linux.org.ua:

> [Download](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=download&dicts=3) = звантажити, стягнути.
>   [Upload](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=upload&dicts=3) = викласти, відвантажити.

<sub>Джерела без розрізнення:</sub>

- <sub>Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко «Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» (2010): [download](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=download&dicts=2) = [upload](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=upload&dicts=2) = завантажити (ще: download = переслати, d. facilities = засоби вивантажити; upload = перевантажити, u. facilities = засоби завантажити).</sub>
- <sub>О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки): частина І англійсько-українська» (2010): [download](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=download&dicts=4) = [upload](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=upload&dicts=4) = завантажити.</sub>
- <sub>Переклади веб-оглядача Chromium на Launchpad: [download](//translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/chromium-browser/uk/+translate?search=download&show=translated&batch=50) ≈ [upload](//translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/chromium-browser/uk/+translate?search=upload&show=translated&batch=50) ≈ (здебільшого) завантажити.</sub>

Інші де-факто використовувані:

> Download: [(с)кач(ув)ати](http://sum.in.ua/s/skachuvaty) ([скачати](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [скачування](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), [качати](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [скачувати](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [качка](//verinet.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/nichna-kachka.jpg)).
>   Upload: [закач(ув)ати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakachuvaty) ([закачати](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [закачувати](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [закачка](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)), [залити](http://webdovidka.com/index.php?newsid=52837), [закинути](//books.google.com/books?id=ACcXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%22).

Інші лише пропоновані:

> Upload: [замереж(ув)ати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=30578&page=1000) ([Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/upload)).

Comment: Мені "передати" має значення "transfer,"  помойому не досить точно.

Comment: @nizz0k, хоча, так, звісно, Ви праві, що *передавати* (transfer) можна в обидва напрямки — тому термін явно не оптимальний.

Comment: подобається "стягнути" і "закинути"

Comment: @Sasha Я більше схиляюся до відповіді PY PY.
Згідно із СУМ-11, вивантажувати - це знімати, виносити, виймати щось,  і це напряму суперечить значенню слова. На жаль, в українській мові, немає чіткого відповідника цьому слову.

Comment: @improbable, а чому «напряму суперечить»?

Comment: @Sasha бо `upload`- це передавати щось кудись, робити копію і класти її на сервер, а не знімати, виносити, виймати цю копію. В даному контексті, логічніше було б `upload`- завантажувати, `download` - вивантажувати, але так склалося, що люди почали використовувати слово завантажувати як переклад до обох слів.

Comment: @improbable, прочитайте, будь ласка, [цей мій коментар](/q/769#comment4662_2695). Можуть бути різні сприйняття напрямку: що (у контексті Інтернету) є _завантажувати_ і що є _вивантажувати_. На моє особисте інтуїтивне сприйняття, download=завантажувати, upload=вивантажувати, але я розумію, що в когось воно протилежне (як і досі не припиняються суперечки про «прокрутити вгору»/«прокрутити вниз» щодо коліщатка миші).

Comment: @Sasha Маєте рацію.

Comment: Відвантажити - це поганий переклад щодо інтернет-терміну. Можна "відвантажити дві тонни цибулі" або у переносному значенні можна "відвантажити півкіло люлей". Так само і вивантажувати можна "палєти з фури". Вантаж -це фізичний об'єкт, який можна зважити. Вжиток ЗАВАНТАЖИТИ припустимий, але не найкращий. Цифровий файл також має визначений розмір і його можна ЗАКАЧАТИ або СКАЧАТИ, тобто передати по інтернет-мережі.

Comment: @Sasha цю відповідь було б добре оновити - з'явилося багато перекладів цих слів на різних сервісах із 2017 - Youtube, Google і т.д. В технічних книжках також. Частина посилань поламалися

Answer (score 6):

Якби «завантажити» початково стосувалось виключно upload, то логічним відповідником для download було б «вивантажити». Проте, так склалось історично, що «завантажити» стали застосовувати до передачі даних в обох напрямках — і на зовнішнє джерело, і з зовнішнього джерела. Більше того, оскільки «вантажити» є недоконанинм і незовсім відповідає за змістом load, «завантажити» вживається і в цьому значенні. А ще є bootstrap — оскільки метафора з «витягуванням себе за шнурки» не пройшла крізь бар'єр перекладів, «завантажити» отримало і цю функцію.

Спроби перепризначити якесь нове слово для upload (звантажити, відвантажити тощо) не надто інтуїтивні й скоріш дискусійні, ніж загальновизнані. Схоже, єдиний спосіб розрізнити download та upload, щоб вас однозначно зрозуміли — це вказати явно, куди відбувається завантаження (на сервер, на локальний комп'ютер тощо). З іншого боку, користувачі україномовних продуктів поступово звикають, що «завантажити» — скоріш за все, download, а будь-яке інше слово, похідне від «вантажити» — це, ймовірно, upload.

Comment: «Якби _„завантажити“_ початково стосувалось виключно _upload_, то логічним відповідником для _download_ було б _„вивантажити“_» — спочатку був подумав, що Ви помилились під час друку і насправді мали на увазі: «Якби _„завантажити“_ початково стосувалось виключно _**down**load_, то логічним відповідником для _**up**load_ було б _„вивантажити“_». Потім зрозумів, що це, мабуть, не помилка, а просто інше сприйняття. Хоча для мене особисто радше download=завантажити, upload=вивантажити.

Comment: Тобто тут ще можуть бути два погляди: варіант А — «мій комп'ютер — наче вантажівка, що завантажується в одному місці Інтернету і вивантажується в іншому, а я наче водій» (мій), варіант Б — «мій комп'ютер — це моя територія, а сторонній сервер „приїжджає“ до мене в гості» (припускаю, що Ваш). І така різниця у сприйнятті різних людей — це ще одне, що додатково заважає остаточно стабілізувати терміни.

Answer (score 1):

[Download](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/download) - копіювати чи переміщувати програми чи інформацію на пам'ять комп'ютера, особливо з Інтернету чи комп'ютера з більшим обсягом пам'яті (тобто ми завантажуємо на ПК).

[Upload](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upload#translations) -  копіювати чи переміщувати програми чи інформацію на комп'ютер з більшим обсягом пам'яті чи в Інтернет (тобто ми передаємо інформацію зі свого ПК на інший пристрій чи в Інтернет).

[Національний online перекладач](https://www.m-translate.com.ua/#text=DOWNLOAD%0A&direction=a-uk) пропонує такі варіанти:

Download - скачати (слово є в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/skachuvaty), однак не має потрібного значення)

Upload - завантажити

[Мета](http://translate.meta.ua/ua/):

Download - завантажити.

Upload - переслати (варіант непоганий, однак не завжди може бути доречним).

[Оnline.ua](https://pereklad.online.ua/ukr/):

Download - завантаження.

А от слово "upload" цей онлайн словник перекласти не зміг.

[Cловенія](http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/download) також перекладає лише "download" як "завантажити", "завантажувати".

Осособисто я вважаю, що переклад обох слів буде залежати від того де і як вони вживаються. Наприклад, "upload photo" не можна перекласти "відвантажити фото", а набагато кращим варіантом буде "завантажити фото" (на сайт). А "download file" також буде хорошим варіантом перекласти як "завантажити файл"(на ПК). Однак, я впевнений, що коли людина здійснює першу чи іншу дію у неї не виникне плутанини через переклад, адже вона розуміє, що саме вона хоче зробити.

Також досить популярним перекладом "download" є дієслово "скачати". Можливо це слово отримає потрібне значення і тоді його можна буде офіційно використовувати для перекладу. А також, на мою думку, можна використати варіант "зберегти", наприклад "зберегти файли".

Або ж можна використати уточнення при перекладі:

Download - завантажити на пристрій.

Upload - завантажити в мережу/ переслати на інший пристрій.

Answer (score 1):

Значення слова load

A heavy or bulky thing that is being carried or is about to be carried.
A weight or source of pressure borne by someone or something.
a load of informal A lot of (often used to express disapproval or dislike of something)
The amount of power supplied by a source; the resistance of moving parts to be overcome by a motor.
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/load?locale=en

Переклад слова load

Вантаж, вага, завага, ладун, навантаження, наклажа, ноша, тягар, вагота, заряд, набій, вантага, набір.

Значення слова down

Toward or in a lower place or position, especially to or on the ground or another surface.
To or at a lower level of intensity, volume, or activity.
In or into a weaker or worse position, mood, or condition.
In or into writing.
(with reference to partial payment of a sum of money) made initially or on the spot.
(of sailing) with the current or the wind.
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/down?locale=en

Переклад слова down

До, ззаду, наниз, униз, унизу, донизу, наспід, занепалий духом, що спадає, спрямований униз, що йде до центру міста,

Значення слова up

Toward a higher place or position.
At or to a higher level of intensity, volume, or activity.
To the place where someone is.
Toward or in the capital or a major city.
Into the desired or a proper condition.
Into a happy mood.
Out of bed.
Displayed on a bulletin board or other publicly visible site.
(of sailing) against the current or the wind.
From a lower to a higher point on (something); upward along.
Directed or moving toward a higher place or position.
At an end.
(of a computer system or industrial process) functioning properly.
In a cheerful mood; ebullient.
(of a jockey) in the saddle.
Denoting a flavor (variety) of stable quark having relatively low mass and an electric charge of +2/3. In the Standard Model protons and neutrons are composed of up and down quarks.
Do something abruptly or boldly.
Cause (a level or amount) to be increased.
Lift (something) up
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/up?locale=en

Переклад слова up

Що піднімається вгору, зростаючий, що йде у велике місце, верхи, вище, нагорі, углиб, догори, нагору, угору, високопоставлена особа, підйом.

Значення слова download

Copy (data) from one computer system to another, typically over the internet.
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/download

"action or process of transferring from the storage of a larger system to that of a smaller one," 1977, from down (adv.) + load (v.). Related: Downloaded; downloading.
https://www.etymonline.com/word/download

Значення слова upload

Transfer (data) from one computer to another, typically to one that is larger or remote from the user or functioning as a server.
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/upload?locale=en

Дослівний переклад

upload — вантажити вгору, download — вантажити вниз

Можливі варіанти

ВАНТА́ЖИТИ
Наповнювати (віз, автомобіль, вагон, судно і т. ін.) вантажем.
https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6603&page=241

ВИ́ВАНТАЖИТИ Зняти, винести вантаж, який перевозиться (підводою, машиною і т. ін.) або звільнити від вантажу (вагони, машини, судна і т. ін.); вийняти.
https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8072&page=297

ВІДВАНТА́ЖИТИ
Навантаживши, відправляти що-небудь кудись
Знімати частину вантажу; перевантажувати в інше місце
Закінчити, перестати вантажити
https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12101&page=401

ДОВАНТА́ЖИТИ
Закінчувати завантажувати; завантажувати до кінця
Завантажувати додатково.
https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22992&page=781

ЗАВАНТА́ЖИТИ
Наповнювати що-небудь (віз, вагон, судно і т. ін.) вантажем (у 1 знач.)
Заповнювати рудою, паливом і т. ін. домну, піч тощо
Передавати інформацію (дані, програми та ін.) з одного інформаційного пристрою до іншого з метою її використання або застосування під час виконання певних операцій
Забезпечувати роботою в належному обсязі
Заповнювати роботою (час)
https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27840&page=931

НАВАНТА́ЖИТИ
Заповнювати що-небудь якимсь вантажем (у 1 знач.); завантажувати
Поміщати, класти вантаж на кого-, що-небудь, у що-небудь
Змушувати працювати що-небудь
Доручати кому-небудь якусь роботу, покладати на кого-небудь якісь обов'язки і т. Ін
https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=53399&page=1703

ПЕРЕВАНТА́ЖИТИ
Переміщати вантаж з одного місця на інше; вантажити з одного транспортного засобу на інший.
Навантажувати надмірно, більше, ніж треба.
[https://goroh.pp.ua/Тлумачення/перевантажувати](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

РОЗВАНТА́ЖУВАТИ
Звільняти кого-, що-небудь від вантажу; знімати, виносити вантаж із машини або якогось іншого виду транспорту.
Звільняти що-небудь від чогось зайвого, непотрібного.
[https://goroh.pp.ua/Тлумачення/розвантажувати](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

Складнощі використання можливих варіантів

Сенс у тому, що жоден з варіантів не має в собі значення напрямків вгору чи вниз. Тому жоден з них не зможе найточніше передати значення перекладу. Як би ви не викручували собі мізки.

Найточніші переносні значення перекладу, про що йде мова, з наявністю схожого відносного напрямку

download — розвантажити, upload — навантажити

Найкращі зрозуміліші відповідники для перекладу одним словом в даному дискурсі, які випливають з тлумачення слів, що не суперечитимуть

**download** — **прийняти**, **upload** — **передати**

Comment: Мабуть, `download — розвантажити` тут не підходить, адже після download файл лише копіюється з сервера на пристрій клієнта. На сервері файл не видаляється, пам’ять там не звільняється.

Comment: @user2513149 В моєму тексті чітко вказано, що варіант, про який ви написали, не підходить. "жоден з них не зможе найточніше передати значення перекладу"

Comment: @user2513149 Це одні з тих слів, які краще асимілювати в українську мову, або використовувати кілька слів для опису значення. Бо просто не вдається знайти слова відповідники.

Answer (score 0):

На мою думку питання полягає лише в пошуку відповідного перекладу слова `load` в контексті передачі данніх. А `up-` та `down-` можуть бути утворені шляхом додавання `на` та `з` відповідно. Наприклад, якщо перекласти `load` як `закачувати`, то `upload` можна буде перекласти як `закачувати на`, а `download` - `закачувати з`.

Answer (score 0):

Download — Отримати / Забрати / Змінити

Upload — Викласти / Зберегти / Додати / Прикріпити

Все залежить від контексту.

не вживати “скачати” — це більш стосується до того, щоб щось скатати в трубочку, а “закачати” — приблизно те саме значення. “Залити” — не підходить, бо хто куди і що лиє.

Comment: Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit]. Сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) підкажуть, як можна покращити ваш допис.

Comment: Інтуїтивно мені подобається _отримати/забрати_ (хоча я б сказав радше _взяти_, а не _забрати_, бо _забрати_ означає, що його _там_ не стало, а _взяти_ — радше що воно з'явилося _тут_) і _викласти/зберегти/додати/прикріпити_. Але до чого тут _змінити_?

Comment: @bytebuster ...викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. — Хм, дякую. Данне питання не може мати чіткої відповіді, її не їснує. Важаю я допоміг автору питання напрямки пошуку у використанні.

Comment: @Sasha є системи які передбачають “Завантаження” файлу для внесення змін локально на компʼютері, а потім “Повернення” нової версії назад на сервер (у систему/додаток).

Comment: @victorq10, дякую, зрозумів… Але, по-моєму, це все-таки дуже частковий випадок. (Хоча, звісно, часткові випадки теж дуже корисні, але, по-моєму, це краще якось явно пояснювати, мовляв, «а для такого випадку ще можливий такий варіант».)

Comment: @victorq10, якщо запитання (на вашу думку) не може отримати об'єктивної відповіді, воно має бути **закритим**. Наразі спільнота не прийняла такого рішення. Коли ви накопичите репутацію, зможете проголосувати за закриття, якщо забажаєте. Але у будь-якому випадку, *погані запитання не заслуговують на відповіді*. Натомість зосередьтеся на якомусь **іншому** запитанні; маємо близько 2,000 запитань, де ваші знання будуть сприйняті більш схвально.

Comment: Друга позиція: цьому запитанню вже 4 роки. Невже ви всерйоз вважаєте, що за 4 роки ніхто не знав, що *download* — це *Отримати / Забрати / Змінити, залежно від контексту*? Відповіді мають нас чомусь навчати. Чому може навчити допис, який містить лише необґрунтовані версії? От якби ви написали те саме слово *«Отримати / Забрати / Змінити»* і послалися на який-небудь словник чи, наприклад, «внутрішню інструкцію для фахівців з локалізації програмного забезпечення фірми Суперсофт» — це було б цікаво і пішло б на користь читачам. Це і відрізняє *хороші* відповіді від *поганих*.

Comment: І ще одне. Завжди варто **читати наявні відповіді** перед тим, як писати свою. По-перше, це позбавляє вас зайвої роботи по створенню дублікатів, а по-друге, дає новим користувачам досвід щодо того, як оформлювати дописи, які дописи краще сприймаються спільнотою тощо. Це покращить якість ваших власних дописів, що і є основною метою цього сайту. Завжди це враховуйте, будь ласка.

Answer (score -2):

```
download -> скачати з сервера

upload <- залити на сервер
```

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit]. Сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) підкажуть, як можна покращити ваш допис.

Comment: було б зручно мати пари, як-от скачати / закачати або залити / вилити.

Comment: ->злити / <-залити