# Як перекласти loading для IT

Tags: переклад, from-english

Онлайн-перекладачi дають декілька варіантів, але жоден, здається, не відповідає комп'ютерній тематиці.
Нібито, `навантаження` є найближчим за значенням, але щось мені у `Зачекайте, будь ласка, йде навантаження` не подобається.

Comment: Зазвичай, «**з**авантаження». «**Н**авантаження» — це може як характеристика («велике навантаження системи»/«висока завантажен**ість** системи»/«high system load»), а як процес здебільшого «**з**авантаження» («завантажуємо компоненти»).

Comment: Чи `завантаження` не ближче до `download`/`downloading`?

Comment: [Мейнарович](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=loading&dicts=2&highlight=on), [ще](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=load&dicts=2&highlight=on); [microsoft](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=loading&langID=uk-ua), [ще](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=load&langID=uk-ua); ну й KDE здебільшого «завантаження» («навантаження» у випадках «навантаження на щось», тобто міра).

Comment: Зрозумiв, не тi перекладачi дивлюсь.

Comment: А які дивитеся, якщо не секрет? (Я, власне, не мав на увазі, що Ви не ті дивитеся — то була відповідь на попередній коментар.)

Comment: А щодо downloading — воно є частковим випадком loading. Не дивно, якщо два порівняно нових поняття, що стоять у відносинах гіперонім-гіпонім одне до одного, передаються одним словом. І download/upload поки єдиного перекладу, як на мене, **[не мають](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/769/4)** (а от loading, як більш широке і просто через брак альтернативних варіантів, по-моєму, має).

Comment: http://cybermova.com/cgi-bin/olenuapro.pl?Word=loading , http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/loading та google.translate

Comment: Ну, в принципі, «триває вантаження даних» — теж варіант. Але так гарно, як в англійській — коротше слово загальне, а префіксами задається напрямок — по-моєму, все одно не вийде. Я маю на увазі, навіть якщо «вантаження» стане найпоширенішим способом передачі англійського «loading», «**за**вантаження», імовірніше, все одно не втратить цього сенсу і не стане відповідником лише для «downloading».

Comment: Можно по-брутальному і коротко: _триває [йде] вантаж_

Comment: @Sasha, перенесiть, будь ласка, ваш коментар у вiдповiдь.

Comment: Є ще менш брутальне — [завантажка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="завантажка"), використовується в документаж вугільної промисловості, тощо, але доволі рідко.

Comment: @br3t, поки що нема часу. Якщо хтось інший створить на основі цих шматків відповідь — я буду лише радий. Але наразі воно додається в *кінець* черги речей-що-давно-їх-збираюся-зробити-на-UkrSE (коли закінчиться поточний проект на роботі — якщо ніхто до цього кращу відповідь не напише, обов'язково перенесу).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Як краще перекласти українською "download" та "upload"?](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/769/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8e-download-%d1%82%d0%b0-upload)

Comment: @br3t а як вам "відвантаження"? Тоді пара "завантаження" - "відвантаження". Я дивився попередні питання і взагалі шукав переклади, але отакого, як я пропоную, ніде не бачив.

Answer (score 5):

Loading… = Завантажується…
Loading program = Завантаження програми

Comment: Наприклад, програма може завантажуватися у пам’ять.